# Laptop does not detect when ethernet cable is plugged in

Tags: windows-10, networking, laptop, ethernet

I have an MSI G65 Stealth with Windows 10.  Any time I plug in an ethernet cable, nothing happens. It still shows "A network cable is unplugged".  I have to disable and enable the adapter before it will connect.  I move my laptop around quite a bit and it's 100% consistent.

The adapter is a Killer E2500 and according to the MSI Driver & App center, all drivers are up to date.

Updated: Here is an `ipconfig` while it is in the state described.  No surprises.

```
C:\
(2021-01-25  7:05:54.96) λ ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : <redacted>
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : <redacted>
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : <redacted>
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : <redacted>
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\
(2021-01-25  7:05:57.46) λ
```

Comment: The most common reason for "A network cable is unplugged" is Windows being unable to communicate with a very specific Microsoft domain.  Sadly, I don't current recall what that domain is exactly, but I suspect it could be related.  Can you [edit] your question and provide the `ipconfig /all` output when the machine is in this state?

Comment: May I know if you can access to Internet via Wi-Fi? Please also check if the methods in the following article was helpful: [How to Fix Ethernet Not Working Issues on Windows 10 & 7](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solutions-to-fix-ethernet-connection-issue/)

Comment: I have updated the question with `ipconfig` output.  Yes, WiFi works fine...  I have updated drivers (since posting the question and beyond laptop manufacturer recommendation). I have replaced the patch cable.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Control Panel/ Device Manager/Network Adaptors / Killer E2500 gigabyte Ethernet Controller/ Properties / Power Management    Uncheck 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power.